# Solubility of integrable systems and the classical XXZ model

Tags: non-linear-systems, spin-models, integrable-systems, integrals-of-motion

I've been learning about [integrability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrable_system) in the Hamiltonian sense, and trying to wrap my mind around the analytic power afforded by integrability, both in quantum and classical systems. My goal with this post is to develop a better intuition for what can be analytically calculated in integrable systems.

More precisely: take a model of two classical spins with Hamiltonian

$$H = J\left(S_{1}^{x}S_{2}^{x}+S_{1}^{y}S_{2}^{y} + \Delta S_{1}^{z}S_{2}^{z}\right)$$

which is just the XXZ Hamiltonian. This system is integrable, in the sense that it has two degrees of freedom and we can construct two integrals of motion: the Hamiltonian itself, and the $z$-component of spin, $S_{1}^{z}+S_{2}^{z}$, which is conserved due to the U(1) symmetry associated with rotations about the $z$-axis.

What kinds of correlation functions can be computed for this model? For example, I would be interested in finding a closed form expression (given some fixed initial conditions) for the quantity $S_{1}^{z}(t)S_{2}^{z}(t)$. Is this possible? It seems difficult because the dynamics of the model are nonlinear, but integrability is very constraining.

**Edit**: I was asked to explain what I mean by classical spins. These are just the types of spins encountered, for example, in the $O(n)$ vector models. They are simply unit vectors completely parameterized by their orientations which satisfy the Poisson brackets $\{S_{i}^{\alpha},S_{j}^{\beta}\} = \delta_{ij}\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma}S_{i}^{\gamma}$.

Comment: What do you mean by "classical" spins?  Perhaps a system whose phase space is $S^2\times S^2$ with a suitable symplectic form?

Comment: There seem to be approx. a dozen known integrable systems (which you can transform into a larger number of equivalent ones). In other words... integrability is a very rare property. In theory we can solve every quantum mechanical problem with a finite number of quanta. It simply boils down to diagonalizing a large matrix. In practice, of course, this leads to the well known speedup of QC vs. CC, which means that no, we can not diagonalize the larger matrices on classical computers.

Comment: @mikestone We can take "classical spins" to be synonymous with unit vectors in three dimensions in this case. I think this is what you have in mind, just said in a more simple minded way.

Comment: Unit vectors yes  ---  but what are the Poisson brackets that give the dynamics? Are they $\{S^i_x,S^j_y\}= \delta^{ij}S^j_z$ and so on?

Comment: Ah I see, yes, sorry, I was taking that as given. I'll add a note to the question.